# Is it possible to change the type of a field when storing an object in MongoDB using Morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a class named Meeting that contains some fields, one of them is timeStamp and its type is long. I want to store meetings in MongoDb, but I want this timeStamp to be stored as a Date. Is there a way to specify Morphia to store it using a different type with a mapper/convertor function?

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
public class Meeting {

    private String entity1;
    private String entity2;
    private long timeStamp;

    public Meeting(){

    };

    public Meeting(String entity1, String entity2, long timeStamp) {

        this.entity1 = entity1;
        this.entity2 = entity2;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getEntity1() {
        return entity1;
    }

    public String getEntity2() {
        return entity2;
    }

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@PrePersist` and `@PostLoad` to coerce the types.  See [here](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.2/guides/annotations/#lifecycle-annotations) for more.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not helpful since I don't want to add another field to this object. The reason I originally saved the timeStamp as a long and not as a Date was to reduce its size.

Comment: You wouldn't be adding another field, you'd be changing the field in the `DBObject` to match the type you want in the database.

I'm not sure you'd save much space doing that as Dates are just 64 bit longs as well.  Profile to be sure, though.